# Shipping Costs With Specific Price Rule

Tags: magento2

We alway's have free shipping on all products. Is it possible that you can create a shopping cart price rule with shipping costs?

Like:

CODE: 10%OFF

Shipping Costs: 4,95

Comment: can not manage shipping coast by rule.use table rates for it

Comment: I can add a rule in my table rates? Don't think that's possible.

The problem is, that when i code comes to €0,00 the customer can't complete the order. So i want at that point shipping costs/administration costs